# 名前付けがうまいと思われるプロジェクト

Tags: 命名規則

個々のファイル名や関数名などで名前付けがうまいと思われるプロジェクトはありますか?

時々githubなどを徘徊して参考にしようとしていますが、これといったものはまだ見つかっていません。

よく使う言語はC++ですが、他の言語でも問題ありません。

例として、あるクラスを定義するファイルを作成する時

1. ファイル名 (例: NamingClass.cpp)
2. クラス名 (例: class ClassName...)
3. 関数名 (例: void DoNameClass(void) )

などがあります。

これらの名前付けがうまいと思われるプロジェクトを知りたいと思います。

Comment: 質問を１つに絞りましょう。タイトルの通り「github上で名付けがうまいと思われるプロジェクトはどれですか？」なのか、「クラス名が決まった時、ファイル名はどれにすべきですか？」の２つの質問が１つに集約されており、どちらに回答すればよいのか判断に困ります

Comment: 名前付けのうまさというのは「この機能をこういう単語で表現する」といった話なのか、キャメルケースにする・ファイル名とクラス名を一致させるなどのルール的な話なのかどちらでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist どちらも知りたいことではありますが、どちらを優先的に知りたいかと聞かれますと「この機能をこういう単語で表現する」といった話です。

Comment: @fkm 混乱させてすみません。質問を一つにするため質問内容を編集しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「クラス名(ClassName)が決まった時、それに対応するファイル名をどのように決めているのか」に関しては、グーグルのjavaコーディング規約に見られるようなものが一般的ではないでしょうか。
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html

これは言語依存でもあるのですが、この方式が一番わかりやすいように思います（私の場合、メインの言語がjavaだからかもしれませんが）。何をもって「名付けがうまい」かというのは難しい問題ですが、それが「どの程度標準的な（よく使われる）ものか」というのは指標の一つになるのではないかと考えています。ですので、例えばgithabで名付けが上手いプロジェクトを１つ探すというよりは、自作のものと似たような機能を持つクラスや関数の、名付け方の最頻値を取ると良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
2.1 File name
「The source file name consists of the case-sensitive name of the top-level class it contains, plus the .java extension.」

5.2.2 Class names
「Class names are written in UpperCamelCase.」

なるほどです。

Comment: クラス名の規約はgoogle規約でもjavaとcppで異なるようですね。どちらを採用するかは検討してみます。